# Put an svg icon inside an empty span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an svg icon inside an empty span, but if I don't put anything in the span it doesn't show me the icon

HTML

```
 <footer>
        <span class="popcorn"></span> 
        <input type="text">
 </footer>
```

CSS

```
footer .popcorn {
background-image: url('./logo.svg');
width: 30px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
display:inline-block;
```

Only works if i put something inside the span example:

```
<span class="popcorn">1</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Background-images won't affect the box model of HTML elements. So while you are defining a width for `.popcorn`, you aren't defining a height.

When you put text content inside of the container, such as in your example, you're implicitly giving the container the height of the line-height of the text, i.e. 16px.

Try giving `.popcorn` a height such as 30px or an aspect-ratio such as 1/1 and see if that solves your issue.